# Numeric value out of range using R, ODBC and DBI

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I have a problem that you could help me to solve.
I had been trying to insert some rows into a table. 
I show you the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Scc_OrdenSevicioFunerarioPagare(
[NumeroPagare] [int] NOT NULL,
[CodigoEstablecimiento] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[NumeroOrden] [int] NOT NULL,
[CodigoClienteAvalista] [int] NOT NULL,
[ValorRecibido] [money] NOT NULL,
[ValorPagare] [money] NOT NULL,
[FechaPago] [date] NOT NULL,
[CantidadPago] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Using R, I had tried to insert the rows with the next code:

```
dsnDesarrollo <- "TESTSQL";
SCC_OrdenServicioFunerarioPagare <- "Scc_OrdenSevicioFunerarioPagare";
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsnDesarrollo, encoding = 'latin1');
dbWriteTable(con, SCC_OrdenServicioFunerarioPagare, dfPagareFuente, append = TRUE);
dbDisconnect(con);
```

My dataframe **dfPagareFuente** only has one row at moment (just for test), the data:

```
(0 <dbl>, 3 <dbl>, 2214 <dbl>, 56239 <dbl>, 2275 <dbl>, 2600 <dbl>, '2017-01-05' <dttm>, 3 <dbl>)
```

But when I tried to run my R code, I got the error:

> Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
>     nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 22003: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Valor numérico fuera del intervalo (Numeric value out of range)

Anyone can give me a clue about what am I doing wrong or any solution to this?

Always thank you.
By the way, I'm using the DBI and odbc library for R.

Comment: Test each column for min/max values in R. One of them is probably outside the range for it's SQL Server data type. The most likely one, in my opinion, is `CodigoEstablecimiento`. Tinyints can only be 0-255 in SQL Server. There is no similar data type in R. It's possible you have a negative number or a large number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

The problem was the FechaPago field. In the table it has date data type, but in R I was trying to insert a datetime value. So I had to cast the values with as.Date in R.

I was able to disccovered when I deleted column by column to identify the problem.

Thank's Steven for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is relevant in this case - but in my case only date was there but was getting error - I solved by converting from Posxit to normal date format using as.Date()